# Generalized Onsager Relation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, reversibility

The usual [Onsager reciprocity relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onsager_reciprocal_relations) states the first order kinetic coefficients form a symmetric matrix. Are there any such relations (from time reversal symmetry) for higher order kinetic coefficients?