Onsager relation in the Casimir Paper
My question is about the paper On Onsager's Principle of Microscopic Reversibility  by Casimir (see page 346, second column).
The relations between forces and currents have the form
$$\dot x_1 = l_{11}f_1 + l_{12}f_2$$
$$\dot x_2= l_{22}f_2 + l_{21}f_1$$.
In some sense he wants to show Onsager relation for when one of the current is zero  (Ex. Seebeck emf)
$$0 = l_{11}f_1 + l_{12}f_2$$
I can not understand following paragraphs, their assumption and their derivation

Next we carry out a virtual displacement $\delta x_1$(in our case we transport a number of molecules) and we assume that the quantity $\delta x_2$, which is
displaced along with $\delta x_1$, is the same as if $f_2$ were zero, so that
$$\delta x_2=\frac{l_{21}}{l_{11}}\delta x_1$$
which means here that $\delta U= Q\delta n$. It is now
assumed that the change of entropy due to the
virtual displacement vanishes:
$$\delta S =0$$
and hence,
$$l_{21}=l_{12}$$


Related, worth checking: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/758419/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178890/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191561/226902

do  you have a question and what is it?

Thanks @Quillo but I need to be more specific.

I want to know the whole process of derivation in the quote part. how the first equation derived? why $\delta U = Q \delta N$ ? what is virtual displacement and why $\delta S=0$? What is this assumption?
@hyportnex
